# Identifying a switch symbol

Tags: schematics, identification, symbol

Is the following sign a switch and if so, what kind if switch is it exactly?

[image: ABB Switch]

It is used in the schematic of the [ABB Eden (Adam & Eva) Module](https://library.e.abb.com/public/96d88945fb4b4395bd7d50233e139f11/Eden_DYN_2TLC172009L0201_B.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like non-latching normally open push button / switch
[image]

And you can see this table in datasheet:
[image]
So you have exact part number of that switch.